# Numpy Array Index Issue

Tags: python, numpy, newtons-method

> I am trying to implement Newtons_method for multivariable scenario. I am trying to output multiple iterations, but am getting an indexing error

```
import symengine
from symengine import var
import numpy as np
vars =var("x y")
sol=[]
def jacob():
    f = ['2*x+y**2-8','x**2-y**2+x*y-3'] # Define function
    J = symengine.zeros(len(f),len(vars)) # Initialise Jacobian matrix
    # Fill Jacobian matrix with entries
    for i, fi in enumerate(f):
        for j, s in enumerate(vars):
            J[i,j] = symengine.diff(fi, s)
            sol.append(J[i,j])
    a = np.array([sol[0],sol[1],sol[2],sol[3]])
    return a

def eval1(func,val1,val2):
    z=[]
    for b in func:
        b=str(b)
        x=val1
        y=val2
        z.append(eval(b))
    return np.array([[z[0],z[1]],[z[2],z[3]]])


def newtons_method(f, df, x0, e):
    q=10
    while q > e:
        q=q-1
        x0 = np.absolute(x0 - (np.array([[f(x0[0][0])],[df(x0[1][0])]]))/(eval1(jacob(),x0[0][0],x0[1][0])))
    print('Root is at: ', x0)
    print('f(x) at root is: ', f(x0))


def f(x):
    return 2*x+y**2-8

def df(x):
    return x**2-y**2+x*y-3
x0s = np.array([[1],[1]])

for x0 in x0s:
    newtons_method(f, df, x0, 1)
```

**I am getting error: invalid index to scalar variable.**
Where I set the value to x0 under the newtons_method function, any ideas as to what is going wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the way you are calling this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling newtons_method function, an element of [[1],[1]] i.e. [1] is being passed as parameter x0. Inside the function, x0[0][0] has been used which gives invalid index to scalar variable error.

You should pass x0s as parameter if you want to use both the elements.

```
x0s = np.array([[1],[1]])
newtons_method(f, df, x0s, 1)
```